# Security Option is Disabled in Kibana 7

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-7

I am new to kibana, exploring kibana 7. there is security feature is disabled. how do i enable that feature? it is paid feature?
I show video on youtube which shows user-management and permission module under security. but when i click on security option under management it shows me Permission Denied Error.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPack Security is a paid feature... until 7.0.1, that is!

If you upgrade to 7.1.0, XPack Security is now FREE (as in free beer) and included in the BASIC license.

Read the announcement here: https://www.elastic.co/blog/security-for-elasticsearch-is-now-free

Enjoy!

Comment: I have upgraded to 7.1.0 but still "permission denied" while accessing localhost:5601/app/kibana#/management/security/users?_g=()

Comment: also tried to set setting in elasticsearch.yml file like xpack.license.self_generated.type: basic xpack.security.enabled:true

Comment: also tried with kibana,yml with xpack.security.enabled:true

Comment: Did you install the full version with BASIC license or the elasticsearch-oss version?

Comment: yes elasticsearch is working, now i am able to access elasticseach with login credentials but kibana stop working. it is shows errors like "Fatal Error “searchguard.readonly_mode.roles” setting was not applied in kibana" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56321941/fatal-error-searchguard-readonly-mode-roles-setting-was-not-applied-in-kibana

Comment: not sure why you have `searchguard` in there... Have you installed the Searchguard security plugin?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56321941/fatal-error-searchguard-readonly-mode-roles-setting-was-not-applied-in-kibana

Comment: above is my question only.

Answer (score 0):

it is tricky.
please first click the APM which will tell your license is not valid.then you click "check license" which will refresh license (it is a basic and free license when it is setup),after some seconds,go back to the icon management,click it.it will show the security settings.I hope I can help you.

[image]